# Difference between a *.lyr and layer directly added from *.gdb/sde to mxd?

Tags: layers, mxd

What is the difference between a  *.lyr  and a layer directly added from *.gdb/sde to mxd?

Doing it difference in mxd?

Which is better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A layer file can store information about how you want one or more layers to look.  This includes symbology, labeling, display scales, definition queries, etc.  If you add a layer directly from a geodatabse or SDE layer, you get the default symbology (generally speaking).  In this respect, layer files are better/more useful.